# Nested dynamically created inputs, Form in Angular

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, nested

I'm trying to get the values inside the inputs of this form.
There is a part where the inputs are generated every time that the user presses the button. 
However, after reading the documentation, I have not clear how should I do the .html in order to get the data properly.

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
<label>
    Capacidad
    <input type="text" formControlName="capacidad">
  </label>
  <label>
    Max. Casas
    <input type="text" formControlName="maxcasas">
  </label>
  <div formArrayName="pesos">
    Peso <button (click)="addPeso()">Añadir peso</button> 
    <div *ngFor="let peso of pesos.controls; let i=index">
      <label>
        Casa:
        <input type="text" [formGroupName]="i">
      </label>
      <label>
        Peso:
        <input type="text" [formGroupName]="i">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

component.ts (where fb is in constructor: `constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)`

```
public formulario = this.fb.group({
    capacidad: ['24300'],
    maxcasas: ['3'],
    pesos: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        peso:   this.fb.control(''),
        nombre: this.fb.control(''),
      })
    ])   
  });
  get pesos(){

    return this.formulario.get('pesos') as FormArray;
  }

  addPeso(){
    console.log(this.formulario.get('pesos'));
    this.pesos.push(this.fb.group([]));
  }
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: the html is not well formed. It is not accessing the inputs correctly. As well, I dont know how to get the input information. I have this.formulario.get('pesos') but that's an array, that has a group inside that has controls (the info I need) inside. I'm not sure how to access that information.

Comment: When you add you want to add new formgroup inside form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating nested form group, you have to use formGroupName directive as a parent of nested controls. Then if you want to access individual form group value use at method which is provide by [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#at)  API to get specific index value.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario">
<label>
    Capacidad
    <input type="text" formControlName="capacidad">
  </label>
  <label>
    Max. Casas
    <input type="text" formControlName="maxcasas">
  </label>
  <div formArrayName="pesos">
    Peso <button (click)="addPeso()">Añadir peso</button> 
    <div *ngFor="let peso of pesos.controls; let i=index"  [formGroupName]="i">
      <label>
        Casa:
        <input type="text" formControlName="peso">
      </label>
      <label>
        Peso:
        <input type="text" formControlName="nombre">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
this.formulario.get('pesos').at(0).value
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2z6a2i)

Comment: Thanks, this goes in the right way, however I get a compile error where you put .at(0),  Property 'at' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. Is there any other more "angular" way to approach this value?

Comment: Tried to, but not working, IDK why. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkbfch

Comment: Inside addPeso method why are you adding empty group?

Comment: I was trying different ways to make it work, this is one of them, no success.

Comment: Try this:: 
  addPeso(){
    console.log(this.formulario.get('pesos').at(0).value);
    this.pesos.push(this.fb.group({
        peso:   this.fb.control(''),
        nombre: this.fb.control(''),
      }));
  }

Comment: Since you are accessing formArray using getter try this:  console.log(this.pesos.at(0).value);

Comment: This worked. I'm very new and I have many doubts with angular. Do you mins helping my with one question: why do I need to use this.pesos.at(0) instead of pesos[0]. Why is ".at" needed here? thanks a lot for your time and consideration.

Comment: At is method Which is provided by formArray API. You can't access form array directly using bracket notation. If you want to access using bracket notation then you have to use controls property inside formarray like this pesos.controls[0]

Comment: Well, I don't know the reason behing but to me sounds like making more difficult what one knows already. Is like having to learn more ways to do exactly the same. Thank you!